# not getting 'order-id' from razorpay script in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-blade, laravel-10

here this is my form that getting submited.

```
`<form id="payment-form" action="{{ route('buyingProduct') }}" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="product" id="product" value="{{ $cart->Product_id }}">
   @csrf
   <input type="hidden" name="final-Price" id="final-price" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="razorpay_order_id" id="razorpay_order_id" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="razorpay_payment_id" id="razorpay_payment_id" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="total_price" id="total_price" value="">

</form>
                
<button id="pay-button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"  onclick="submitPaymentForm()">Pay</button> `
```

this is form i am using in my project in cart.blade.php page , here i am using razorpay payment system in myproject.now i am getting payment-id from the form, but i am not getting 'order-id'. here On click of that button Below Script will be executed

```
 <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
                  function submitPaymentForm() {
                    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
                    var name = document.getElementById('product-name');
                    var amount = document.getElementById('final-price').value * 100;
                    
                    var options = {

                      key: '{{ env("RAZORPAY_KEY") }}',
                      amount: amount,
                      name: name,
                      description: 'test',
                      image: 'test',
                      prefill: {
                        name: '{{ auth()->user()->name }}',
                        email: '{{ auth()->user()->email }}'
                      },
                      theme: {
                        color: '#ff7529'
                      },

                      "handler": function (response){
                        console.log(response);
                        document.getElementById('razorpay_order_id').value = response.razorpay_order_id;
                        document.getElementById('razorpay_payment_id').value = response.razorpay_payment_id;
                        document.getElementById('final-price').value = amount / 100;
                        document.getElementById('payment-form').submit();
                      },
                    };
                
                    var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
                
                    rzp1.on('payment.failed', function(response){
                      console.log(response.error.code);
                      console.log(response.error.description);
                      console.log(response.error.source);
                      console.log(response.error.step);
                      console.log(response.error.reason);
                      console.log(response.error.metadata.order_id);
                      console.log(response.error.metadata.payment_id);
                    });
                
                    rzp1.open();
                  }
     </script>
```

from above form i am not getting value of 'Order-id' in response.razorpayorder_id